# Lua expected = near elseif

Tags: lua

I am getting an error being returned when trying to run an elseif requiring me to put a = near elseif but I have used the same method before and no problem as been returned.

```
if ((GAMEPLAY.GET_DISTANCE_BETWEEN_COORDS( -629.99, -236.542, 38.05 , location.x, location.y, location.z, true ) < 2 ))  then
        setMessage("Press E to start the heist.")
        --SelectPart(1) --start
        heistP[1]
    elseif ((startH == true) and (jewelPart == false) and (escape == false) and (dropoffP == false)) then

        heistP[2]
        --SelectPart(2) --loadBlips
    elseif ((jewelPart == true) and (escape == false) and (dropoffP == false)) then
        --SelectPart(3) -- Jewels
    elseif ((escape == true) and (dropoffP == false)) then
        setMessage("Escape the cops!")
        --SelectPart(4) --EscapeC
    elseif (dropoffP == true) then
        --SelectPart(5) --DropOff
    end

heistP = {
  [1] = function()
    local playerPed = PLAYER.PLAYER_PED_ID()
    local location = ENTITY.GET_ENTITY_COORDS(playerPed, nil)
    if(get_key_pressed(Keys.E))then
        PLAYER.SET_PLAYER_WANTED_LEVEL(PLAYER.GET_PLAYER_PED(playerPed),3,false)
        --PLAYER.SET_PLAYER_WANTED_LEVEL_NOW(PLAYER.GET_PLAYER_PED(playerPed),false)
        PED.SET_PED_COMPONENT_VARIATION(playerPed, 9, 1, 0, 0)
        startH = true
    end
end,

}
```

Comment: What's the code around the elseif? Also you can simplify that to `elseif startH and not jewelPart and not escape and not dropoffP then`

Comment: Is that the actual line number it says the error is on?  It would be best to include the whole if/elseif/end in the question.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Sorry, I will post it now and yes it is the actual line number.

Comment: The problem appears to be `heistP[1]` and `heistP[2]`.  What did you expect those to do?  If I comment them out the syntax is correct.

Comment: @Retired Ninja Indeed HeistP is a table containing functions I will add it to main post

Comment: You most likely want `heistP[1]()` to call the function.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you very much I didn't know you had to put in () as I though since it was in the () were in the table I didn't think I would need to put them else where due to the fact I wasn't calling it with params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`heistP[1]` and `heistP[2]` should be `heistP[1]()` and `heistP[2]()`. I'm assuming `heistP[2]()` is defined somewhere else, if not, you need to define it.